# Abrir leitor de disco com Java, e sem especificar a unidade

Tags: java

Queria se possível uma forma simples e rápida de abrir o leitor de disco sem especificar a letra da unidade. Existem várias maneiras porque eu já vi.

Comment: Veja essa [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829113/how-to-open-cd-drive-java) no StackOverflow.

Comment: Eu geralmente apertava o botão na frente da unidade, naquela época que as maquinas usavam essas mídias. /s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não diretamente em Java, mas estas alternativas pode ser chamadas como aplicativo externo usando `exec()`:

Script [tirado do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467897), para Windows, em linha de comando + VBScript. Salve como batch (.bat) ele mesmo chama a parte auto-contida em VBScript:

ejetar.bat

```
:sub echo(str) :end sub
echo off
'>nul 2>&1|| copy /Y %windir%\System32\doskey.exe '.exe >nul

'& cls
'& cscript /nologo /E:vbscript %~f0
'& pause

Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7" )
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection

if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
        For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
                colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
        Next ' cdrom
End If
```

Se precisar fazer o mesmo em linux, geralmente as distibuições já vem com o utilitário `eject`, que pode ser usado diretamente no shell ou chamado pelo seu aplicativo:

```
eject /dev/cdrom
```

Também temos o projeto `eject` no SourceForge, de código aberto caso queira ver como funciona:

http://eject.sourceforge.net/

Todas as propostas que eu vi em Java (confesso não ter procurado demais) usam ajuda de alguma coisa externa, aparentemente por falta de abstração da camada necessária nas difersas implementações da VM.

[Aqui, mais um link que usa VB](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0574.html), desta vez gerado pelo próprio java. Mas, como toda ferramenta externa, depende do OS.

Caso precise de mais detalhes, edite sua pergunta acrescentando um contexto mais restrito para que possamos ajudar mais.

Comment: Obrigado campeão!